# Create alias for desktop directory

Tags: bash, shell, alias, cd-command

If I type in `cd Desktop`, no matter what folder the terminal is currently open in, I want it to navigate to `/home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop`

In my `.bashrc` file I have the following lines at the bottom:

`alias desktop='/home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop'`

`alias Desktop='/home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop'`

and then I source it, but when I type in `cd Desktop` or `cd desktop` it still gives the same error?

Comment: Aliases only replace a command (so the first word in the command line) - you can't use them to replace command-line arguments

Comment: How can I do this then?

Comment: "how can I do it then?" Two ways. You can create a new "desktop" alas/function. `desktop(){ cd $HOME/Desktop ; }` or you can set the CDPATH variable to "$HOME:." and use "cd Desktop"

Comment: Just be aware with the second suggestion by @icarus (`CDPATH`) this would make `cd` always go to a directory in your home directory over a directory in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> alias desktop='/home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop'
> cd desktop
> ```

An alias is for a command name. A parameter to the `cd` command is not a command name. The alias is not used in this context.

If you type just `desktop`, this invokes the alias. But by default you'll get an error

```
bash: /home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop: Is a directory
```

Add the line `shopt -s autocd` to your `~/.bashrc` so that typing a directory name in command position performs `cd` to that directory. This way you can change to the directory `~/Desktop` by typing just `~/Desktop` (instead of `cd ~/Desktop`) or, with your alias, `desktop`.

Alternatively, define an alias to a command that works:

```
alias desktop='cd /home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

- You can make a variable for `$desktop` and/or `$D` as a shortcut for it.
- You can `alias desktop='cd /home/bob-ubuntu/Desktop'`
- You can use `$USER/Desktop`
- You can use `$XDG_DESKTOP_DIR` if [XDG](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_user_directories) user directories is set.
- You can add `/home/bob-ubuntu` to `CDPATH` environment variable of `cd` command

But you are really better off just using:

```
cd ~/Desktop
```

Tilda shouldn't hurt! :D

Note that you can also use tilda to switch to `$HOME` directories of many users in your system as follows:

```
cd ~root
ls ~ftp
echo ~nobody
```

Answer (score 0):

As icarus suggested in the comments, one simple way is to create an alias that does `cd ~/Desktop`

However if you really want `cd` to behave this way, you can alias a function to `cd` that handles checking if the directory is `Desktop`:

```
_cd () {
  if [ "$1" == "Desktop" ]; then
    cd ~/Desktop
  else
    cd $1
  fi
}
alias cd="_cd"
```

However this also causes tab completion for `cd` to break